# Why color of appbar is not changing in flutter after declaring primary color?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, flutter-layout

I have declared primary color to Color(0xFF0C9869) to this which is kind of green color but the appbar is always blue until I change it in appbar widget why is my primary color not working. I am running this code in android studio.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plant/components/home.dart';
import 'package:plant/constraint.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: kTextColor),
      ),
      home: Homescreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

constraint.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF0C9869);
const kTextColor = Color(0xFF3C4046);
const kBackgroundColor = Color(0xFF9F8FD);

const double kDefaultPadding = 20.0;
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class Homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Homescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(),
    );
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/menu.svg")
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to declare it in appBarTheme in ThemeData .

```
    theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: kTextColor),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor),
  ),
```